# how to install retrofit extension in robospice

Tags: android, networking, roboguice

I have searched the wiki but could not find the procedure to use the various extensions for robospice. I have downloaded the various jars for robospice. It is not clear how the extensions (esp. retrofit) must be imported into eclipse.

Any help/procedure is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The retrofit specific jars are in the dependencies package of the repository branch

https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/tree/repository

Use the jars from there